# Passing jQuery var into progress bar style

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get a progress bar working on my project to display how much stock is remaining in a stock room

Below is my code for the progress bar, what i would like to do is run a jQuery to my AJAX file which does the right maths and passes back a value to put in the `style="width: "` tag.

My problem is i don't know how to pass the variable into that part using jQuery. I had a look at some other methods but nothing really showed me how to do it on this level. Would it be right to use the .append command?

```
<div class="progress" style="height: 30px">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" style="width: !!VARIABLE HERE!!%" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" >Remaining Stock: <?=$dec?>%</div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: if you're not using any templating to you html it'll be hard passing variables to controllers. you can use click event and invoke a function that adds style with js

Comment: this can be easily achieved using templates, ie: lodash

Comment: https://codepen.io/gustitammam/pen/RRXGdj

Comment: for example `$('.progress-bar').css('width', varHere);`

Comment: many templating and mvvm engines do NOT support placeholders for attributes so it is not clear if what youn use can support it, but setting the style directly through jquery as my previous comment can do it

Comment: thanks for all your help and suggestions :) i'm just writing the ajax now so will try these methods soon. I have some similar jQuery so hopefully i'll be able to adapt that to make it work :) thanks again

Comment: @NikosM. - that codes doesn't seem to do anything :(

Comment: did you use an actual value variable where `varHere` is present?

Comment: yeah i changed to my var (per). I can get it to work if i set the value as `$_SESSION['per']` then then just `style="width:<?=$_SESSION['per']?>%"` in the form, i was just hoping to get it done with that jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use jQuery like this:

```
$(".progress").css("height": "30px");
```

Comment: just to clarify, it's the style of the Div below it i would like to change :)